# joomla module on submit refresh page

Tags: forms, module, joomla2.5

I have the following situation

Joomla 2.5
I have 2 modules on the page
1. in first module I have a form submit to itself, it then sets an registry variable. (use setUserState)
2. in the second module I will read the registry variable and update the view accordingly, (use getUserState)

The problem is, when first module submits, it only update it self, not the page or other module. How can I force the update on entire page, or atleast notify the other module to read the registry variable.

Comment: Is the form being submitted via AJAX?

Comment: just a simple php submit to it self

Comment: I noticed its not the module 2 is not refreshed, it is it refresh too fast, so the change module 1 did didnt make it.